# Is there a tool which will package a copy of the JRE with my application so that it can run regardless of whether or not the user has Java installed?

Tags: java

This is my first brush with actually distributing a Java application. I'm coming from a Python background, which has a fantastic set of tools for distribution called PyInstaller, and Py2App. Both of these package up a copy of the Python Interpreter along with the application so that there's nothing to install for the end user. They simple see an `.EXE` or `.app` double click it, and the program starts.

So far, I have been unable to find a similar tool for Java. The idea behind this app is that it's stored on a flashdrive so it can be run without installing anything on the host machine.

I've found decent tools for Windows. For instance, [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) appears to do the trick, but it's for windows only. I'm desperately in need of similar functionality, but for making an app.

Has anyone faced this conundrum before? Are there any tools which I could use?

Comment: Do you have rights to distribute JRE?

Comment: Have you considered using JWS?

Comment: @Perception Unfortunately not an option, as internet is seldom available, and/or unreliable where I'm distributing these things.

Comment: For some reason my posted answer is being downvoted and deleted despite it being a direct answer to your question.  In any case since you have explicitly stated below you don't want to pay $2k for a license for Install4J you may want to look at JWrapper since it does the same thing for free.

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume you are distributing via a .zip file

You could drop a copy of the JRE in your app directory, then create a .bat and .sh script that will run the app with a java command using the JRE that is in the same directory.

There is probably a better tool to do this but this is one way it could be achieved.

A super simplified example .sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

jre/bin/java myapp.jar
```

Would run myapp.jar using the JRE in that location. In reality you would want to put checks to make sure the JRE exists.

the app folder:

```
myapp/
    jre/
    start.sh
    start.bat
    myapp.jar
```

the jre would be an actual JRE instance.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit on the exact process for copying the JRE/starting it with an .sh file? I'm actually a complete newbie with the OSX side of things. Hense my choice of Java. I thought it would help with a smooth transition from Windows to Macintosh.

Comment: Sure I have added extra to my answer

Comment: I'm either blind, or really dense.. I cannot for the life of me find the JRE on OS X. Your suggestion works beautifully on windows, but I'm like an 90 year old when navigating the mac. I cannot find a JRE directory, however it does have a `Home` directory, so I've tried copying that, but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), it's a multi-platform Java installer (and launcher) builder. You can bundle a JRE with your installers.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops install4j

Comment: I wish I could use that! However, at $2k+ for a cross platform license, it unfortunately sits a little (a lot) beyond my means.

Comment: If you need it for an open source project, we do offer open source licenses: http://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/openSource